# How to use guestfs rsync-in and rsync-out?

Tags: go, virtual-machine, rsync, qemu

I am using guestfs Go bindings. I am creating the qcow2 to take the backup of my dir. While doing a backup, I was using CopyIn operation. This is taking a long time to copy the big file. I came across rsync-in and rsync-out. I tried these functions using guestfs functions and as well as with guestfish commands but facing many issues. I don't see any example or help for the same.
I am searching for answers to the following questions,

1. What are the pre-steps that are required to make the rsync-in, rsync-out work? How to setup the rsync daemon on the host machine for guesfs APIs/guestfish?
2. Simple rsync-in and rsync-out example